# Convert case of an HTML page to lower in R

Tags: r, stringr

I need to convert all content of an HTML page to lower. But I got an error.

```
library(stringr)
library(httr)
library(XML)

url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/"
request <- GET(url)
doc <- htmlParse(request, encoding = "UTF-8")
doc <- str_to_lower(doc)
```

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") :    cannot coerce type
>   'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'

My need is to keep the XML structure of the doc cause I will have to use xpath.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't... I first need to convert all elements in lower before to extract them. I have chosen this method cause I have to extract element that match a list I have created and by converting all elements in lower ( + removing all accents) before, that allows me to reduce the number of elements in my list.

Comment: I would try `doc <- content(request, "text")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to convert the doc into characters, change the case and then repeat the parsing into HTML code.

```
library(stringr)
library(httr)
library(XML)

url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/"
request <- GET(url)

#convert to character then covert case
newdoc<-str_to_lower(as.character(request)) 

#reread the new doc to convert back to html   
doc <- htmlParse(newdoc, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

This should create the desired readable document.

Comment: Hello @Dave2e, thanks for your reply but this doesn't work. There is an error when creating the newdoc variable : Error in as.vector(x, "character") : cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: @Remi, Sorry corrected error.  Need to change case of the Get(URL) call and not the htmlParse.  See above, this should work now.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e, It works now but there is one thing that is strange in the doc variable. All content attribute in meta and other tags have been transformed.   For exemple a meta description like this <meta http-equiv="description" name="description" content="hello I am a meta description">, now looks like this
<meta http-equiv="description" name="description" content="hello"  I am a meta description> (The quotation marks are closing on the first word inside the content attribute). Do you have any idea how to fix it?